# Bugsnag Upload dsym files

Tags: ios, upload, crash, dsym, bugsnag

I followed bugsnag‘s documentation and found a few xcarchive file using the mfind UUID command.

```
$ mdfind YOUR_UUID_HERE
path/to/dsyms/MyApp.dSYM
$ bugsnag-dsym-upload path/to/dsyms
```

Here is the documentation:
https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/ios/symbolication-guide/

In the terminal it showed that the upload was successful however I can not see it in the bugsnag dashboard of the project under uploaded dSYMs.

Does anyone how to upload dSYM files to bugsnag?

Comment: Hi! You can raise a support request by contacting us at support@bugsnag.com and we'd be more than happy to assist. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Bugsnag support and could solve it.
If I add my API key to the last command which uploads the dSYM files it works!

```
bugsnag-dsym-upload --api-key API_KEY path/to/dsyms
```